# JMeter takes 3 minutes to open 3mb jmx script file

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, load, jmx

I am using jmeter 5.1.1. When I start jmeter, it opens immediately. But when i try to open my jmx script file having size greater than 3mb, jmeter takes 3 to 4 minutes to open.
It opens the small files within short time.

My script has 3 listeners.

Heap size configured is 1 gb. but still its the same issue.

i think it should not take much time just for opening the script.

Comment: Does it opens and runs properly 3-4 minutes? My guess is either your script has errors and/or your laptop/desktop is unable to handle your configurations on the script.

Comment: It runs properly after opening but just for opening script,  it takes 3 minutes. I have 8 gb ram.

Answer (score 0):

After some R&d, I got an answer. Issue is with Jmeter Theme Selection.

My jmeter was running with "Darcula" theme. Only "Darcula" theme takes too much and jmeter gets hung up.

If you try any other theme (metal, nimbus, CDE/Motif, Windows, Windows Classic, Cross Platform, System) script does only takes 2 to 4 seconds maximum.

I recommend do not use "Darcula" theme.